# Filezilla Server keeps asking for password on boot

Tags: windows-7, ftp, filezilla

Every time I start my computer this screen appears:

[image]

Usually this doesn't happen, it just logsin silently minimized in system tray.

I already tried checking "Always connect to this server".

Edit: I found that my settings are not being saved every time I close/open the admin interface.

Any ideas how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Deleting said XML file and starting the Server Interface as an Admin (go to the directory it's installed in, right click the server interface exe and chose run as admin) helped.
It seems otherwise the interface is not storing the settings properly.

Answer (score 0):

To those having the same issue, I've found the *FileZilla Server Interface.xml* file under the installation directory got corrupted. I just deleted this and FileZilla regerated a new one which solved the problem.